# Using regex to strip all characters and punctuation from a string except apostrophe

Tags: ruby, regex

I attempted to let this method call:

```
alternate_words(". . . .  don’t let this stop you")
```

return every other word in the string, less punctuations except for `'`.

This is the method definition:

```
def alternate_words(sentence)
  sentence.gsub(/[^a-z0-9\s']/i, "").split(" ").delete_if.with_index 
  {|word,index| index.odd? }
end
```

The result is:

```
["dont", "this", "you"]
```

The correct words are returned, but no `'` is included. Changing the regex to:

```
/[^a-z0-9\s][']/i
```

returns

```
[".", ".", "don’t", "this", "you"]
```

Now, it correctly recognizes the apostrophe, but it incorrectly includes the periods. I don't understand why.

Comment: What you have in the original string doesn't look like a single quote that you mention in the question.

Comment: ``'‘’′ʻ`´`` can easily be mistaken for each other.

Answer (score 0):

You may actually *match* words with apostrophes and hyphens with `scan`:

```
def alternate_words(sentence)
  sentence.scan(/[[:alnum:]]+(?:[’'-][[:alnum:]]+)*/).delete_if.with_index { |_,index| 
    index.odd? 
  }
end

p alternate_words(". . . . .  don’t let this stop you")
# => ["don’t", "this", "you"]
```

See a [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/DDv7Wq)

The `[[:alnum:]]+(?:[’'-][[:alnum:]]+)*`  pattern may be enclosed with a word boundary - `\b` - if you want to only match *whole* word.

**Details**:

- `[[:alnum:]]+` - 1 or more alphanumeric symbols
- `(?:[’'-][[:alnum:]]+)*` - zero or more (due to `*`, replace with another quantifier as per requirements) occurrences of:

  - `[’'-]` - an apostrophe or a hyphen (the list may be adjusted_
  - `[[:alnum:]]+` - 1 or more alphanumeric symbols.